# Enable-Disable cells of single column in Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel

Tags: extjs3

I have **EditorGridPanel** and I want Enable-disable cell values depending on other column value of same Row and I am using **Extjs 3**. As I tried to find out a solution on Google there is I found that
I can able to use **RowEditing plugin**. I don't want to use this plugin, so is there another way to do this?

And I want to do this enable and disable when click on Edit button, so I can able to do this on **"beforeedit"** event. 
here I am getting issue that how I can able to access one particular cell object and how I can able to enable and disable that cell object. There is method to enable-disable whole column of
grid but is there any method which returns that particular cell object and enable-disable this cell object?

Is anyone knows is there any way to do this, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:**

As I previously considering "beforeedit" event is fire for row but it's fire for each cell which we click. So I get field name first as **"var fldname= e.field;"** and then I am returning false for matched field to make it disable for   Ex:  var fldname= e.field;

```
onBeforeEdit : function(e) {
var fldname= e.field;
if(fldname == "FirstName" || fldname = "LastName"){
return false;
}
```

so it disables "FirstName" and "LastName" columns of grid.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intentions correctly, you should have a look here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel-event-beforeedit

And, as far as I understood, here's the method you have been looking for: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridView-method-getCell

Combining these two together, you should have a similar function as a listener for 'beforeedit' event of your EditorGridPanel.

```
onBeforeEdit : function(e) {
    var htmlCell = e.grid.getView().getCell(e.row, e.cell);
    Ext.fly(htmlCell).addClass('disabled');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply medvarztis, It's worked for me now. As I previously considering "beforeedit" event is fire for row but it's fire for each cell which we click. So I get field name first as **"var fldname= e.field;"** and then I am returning false for matched field to make it disable for Ex: